# How to call default method of a jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the a jquery plugin called bonsai (http://aexmachina.github.io/jquery-bonsai/) basically this helps creating a tree view structure of elements.

All works fine, I am trying to expand a single node VIA code, though I can see that plugin have a default method to expand a single node

```
      $.bonsai.defaults = {
        expandAll: false, // boolean expands all items
        expand: null, // function to expand an item
        collapse: null, // function to collapse an item
        checkboxes: false, // requires jquery.qubit
```

Implementation looks like :

```
Bonsai.prototype = {
        initialised: false,
        expand: function( listItem ) {
            this.setExpanded(listItem, true);
        },
```

Still I am not able to figure out how to call this method, tried different ways but nothing worked.

My code looks like :

```
<ol id='searchType'>
            <li class='expanded'>
                <b>Partner Type</b>
                <ul>
                    <li>TextBox</li>
                    <li>CheckBOX</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class='expanded'>
                <b>Region</b>
                <ul>
                    <li>Asia-Pacific</li>
                    <li>Europe, Middle East & Africa</li>
                    <li>Global</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
</ol>
```

Binding :

```
   $('#searchType').bonsai()
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the docs? What have you tried?

Comment: @ZeeTee: There isn't much in them, expandAll works, not able to make expand() work.

Comment: Show the HTML and how you're binding it to the element, without that it's nearly impossible to help

Answer (score 0):

This is how the doc's say to implement it:

```
 $('#checkboxes').bonsai({
   expandAll: true,
   checkboxes: true // depends on jquery.qubit plugin
 });
```

The defaults you have loaded goes on top, and all the `.bansai()` methods used in scope will inherit those defaults.

You can see more info on the authors site: http://aexmachina.github.io/jquery-bonsai/

---

EDIT:

The reason they are not all expanding on initialization is because you've disabled this option in your defaults.

change your defaults from `expandAll: false` to `expandAll: true` (or add it to your element initialization) and it should expand all.

Comment: Have you tried binding the `expanded` class to all the li's you want expanded. The doc's make this clear to use `class='expanded'`

Comment: That's for the initial expand, I need to do it via code, adding expanded class at run time doesn't trigger the expand function.

Answer (score 0):

maybe Its a little late, but I was looking for the same thing and I managed to solve it triggering a "click" event.
Something like this, to expand all:

```
$('#my-bonsai div.thumb').trigger('click');
```

Or maybe this, to expand the first item

```
$('#my-bonsai > li > div.thumb').firs().trigger('click');
```

Hope it helps